# Can I use stoi with GCC 4.4.7 compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc

I don't want to use -std=c++11.
Is there another way ?

I have this peace of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "45";

    int myint1 = std::stoi(str1); <--error: Function 'stoi' could not be resolved
}
```

Comment: You can't use std::stoi() without -std=c++11.

Comment: And even if you wanted to, Gcc 4.4.7 does not support C++11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you question is "Can I use stoi with GCC 4.4.7 compiler?", then

**Yes**, you can use `std::stoi` with `-std=c++0x`. GCC 4.4 does not have much of support for fancy C++11 features, but it does support simple C++11 functions like `std::stoi`. Check this [support table](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) out for GCC 4.4's support for C++0x.

Answer (score 4):

`stoi` is from C++11, so if you don't want to use flag `-std=c++11` you cannot use `stoi` (or you can wait until gcc 6.0 will be released, where `-std=gnu++14` will be default standard).

But you can use something else: `boost::lexical_cast`, some manually written function, etc.